# How to make SVN ADD ignore binaries

Tags: svn, binary, directory, addition, ignore

Binaries (under Linux) don't have an extension so I cannot exclude them using patterns. Thus when I use `SVN add` to add a directory I will get something like

```
$ svn add recursion_vector/
A         recursion_vector
A         recursion_vector/rec_vec.cxx
A         recursion_vector/rec_vec.h
A  (bin)  recursion_vector/rec_vec
```

Here `rec_vec` is the executable I would like to exclude. SVN obviously recognizes it as binary. Now can I tell Subversion to ignore all binary files?

Comment: Just a remark: Ignoring all binaries would ignore other binaries, too. Like, for example, icons, which you might want to include in the repository.

Comment: Yes, but that's something I could live with, because I normally only check in code and never icons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit verbose because it uses find:

`find [TARGET-DIRECTORY] \( -executable -type f \) -prune -o -print | xargs svn add --depth empty`

Passing the target-directory to find, find will recurse the directory printing out all the contents except for executable files (`\( -executable -type f \) -prune`).  Without `-type f` find would also prune directories since these usually have the execute bit or "search bit" set.

The `--depth empty` option on `add` tells svn not to itself recurse a file object, since find is handling the recursion.

If you like the result, you can put this in a shell function that would allow you to pass in arguments for `[TARGET-DIRECTORY]`.

Thank you,

Zachary

Answer (score 1):

Can you set up a pattern match to exclude filenames that don't have a `.` in them?

Comment: The best idea so far :) Of course, it would also fire on files called README and similar, but I don't have those, so maybe I should go with this.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig you could also match filenames that don't have a `.` in them and also match `[a-z]+`. If you work with README files, then they may all be `[A-Z]+`...

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want (and you might already know this answer)... but anyway :

You can set exclude patterns to ignore some files based on the filenames. More info in the great SVN book :

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3

Other than that, it might be possible to do something with commit hooks, but I have no experience with those ...

Good luck !