# "svn add myFolder" command don't add binary files

Tags: svn, command-line

I've a strange but maybe normal behavior.

When I do a "`svn add myFolder`", it adds the folder with all the files inside expected binary files.
I have to do a "`svn add myFolder/*`" as second command to add the missing binaries, but it raise error about the other already added files.

Is this normal or there is a way to do the two command as one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering this [almost perfectly opposite question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191203/how-to-make-svn-add-ignore-binaries), and the fact I don't remember any issue like that, I'd guess your repository has some `svn-ignore` attributes set that filter some file types out. Also, the behaviour of `svn add xxx/*` matches, since it explicitely targets all the files one after another, and this as far as I remember would bypass the svn-ignore.

So.. I'd say, check your svn-ignores. Also, remember that they can be defined on each directory separately, not only at the root folder of the repository, so better check your current and all parent directories as well.

Comment: Gonna look and come back :)

Answer (score 4):

```
svn add --no-ignore myFolder
```

This will add both normal and binary files.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
I got a script to use to prevent those problemes :

```
#!/bin/sh
svn status | grep '^?' | awk '{print $2}'  | xargs svn add
svn status | grep '^!' | awk '{print $2}'  | xargs svn delete
svn commit -m ""
```